# Deserializing json using gson

Tags: java, json, deserialization, gson

I have a problem with deserializing following json:

```
{
   "17":"asdf",
   "18":"fdsa",
   "19":"gfds",
   "34":"vcxz",
   "35":"oiue",
   "36":"oiuy"
}
```

to:

```
public class CategoryList {

    List<Category> list;
}

public class Category {

    String id;
    String name;
}
```

I receive following `IllegalStateException`:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
```

Please tell me where I make mistake.

Comment: Please put the code you're running (which throws IllegalStateException)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following json

```
{
   "17":"asdf",
   "18":"fdsa",
   ...
}
```

is a JSON object not an array. 
Your classes (Category and CategoryList) should consume a following json:

```
{
    list: [
        {id: 17, name: "asdf"},
        {id: 18, name: "fdsa"},
        ....
    ]
}
```

Change your json or classes.

EDIT: The problem is that (if I understand your sample) your json object has a variable number of fields. This means you have to use something like hashmap instead of your classes. Try to deserialize your json to

```
Map<int, String>
```

You can find some help in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8103092/2880555 (you will be redirected to this link http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/06/gson-v-jackson.html and asked for search "Gson Code to turn any JSON object into a Map" in that page).

Comment: could you tell me how should I change classes to consume it without changing a json?

Comment: @pawegio answer was extended with more info.

Comment: thanks! That's what I needed. Finally I decided to change json, because it is "cleaner" solution (as I think).

Comment: @pawegio if you have possibility to change a json - it's definitely a better idea. It's self describing and far more readable. You know that "18" is an ID and "fdsa" is a name. And it works better with your objects in java - you will have a list of categories instead of strange Map<int,String>.

Answer (score 1):

The error is fairly self-explanatory, the deserialiser expects a JSON array, because your class contains a `List`.

Try the following JSON:

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "id": "17",
            "name": "asdf"
        }
    ]
}
```

which should serialise correctly